# Scene.JS Resources

Tags: webgl, scenejs

I am trying to learn WebGL using the popular Scene.JS library which apparently suits my application more than three.js(scientific visualization).
However there seems to be a dearth of tutorials and learning resources for it.
Can someone point me to some good ones? 
I could find some fairly good ones for three.js but none for scene.js!

Comment: I'm not sure why this is tagged in Three.js if this is a specifically non-Three.js question. Good luck finding the information you need!

Comment: Have you googled "scenejs"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://scenejs.org/examples.html seems to be only place with examples.
But it has quite a lot of examples that are also pretty well commented.
Also there is github repo (xeolabs/scenejs) so if you encounter some problem there might be an explanation of how to resolve it on Issue section on github.

Node-like structure of engine is not that intuitive as Three.js' structure( aldo it has it's own advantages) so it's not being used very much.

Hope this helps.